# Reducing memory usage for dynamic programming implementation of TSP

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, traveling-salesman

I'm trying to implement dynamic programming to solve TSP for a set of 25 cities.
With the straight-forward implementation the program I'm facing 'memory error'. I'm trying to solve it by taking into account that my implementation needs only subsets which are of size 1 less than the current subsets, i.e. the sub-problem in dynamic programming is the current set with one element removed. Hence only the distances corresponding to current and previous sizes,(sizes vary from 2 to 25), are stored. Still, the program eats almost 85% of memory and then throws error. My system has 4GB of RAM.
How can I fix the code so that its memory usage doesn't explode?

```
def make_set(i):
    '''Generates all subsets of size i(integer)
        from cities, including the element 1'''
    cities = range(2,26)
    subs = comb(cities,i)
    for j in subs:
        j=set(j)
        j.add(1)
        yield j

def tsp(cities,dist):
    '''Performs search on subsets to find shortest path that traverses
       all cities starting and ending at 1
       Returns a dictionary, contains all 
       needs to be processed further to find the subset_dist answer'''
    subset_dist={}
    subset_dist[(frozenset([1]),1)]=0
    for i in range(1,25): 
        subset_dist_new={}
        subsets = make_set(i) #generator for subsets of size i
        for S in subsets:
            for j in S:       # j is the destination
                if j!=1:
                    min_dist= float('inf')
                    S_minusJ = set(S)
                    S_minusJ.remove(j)
                    for k in S:     #k defines the subproblem, the closest city before j, for current subset
                        if k==1 and len(S)>2:
                            continue
                        if k!=j:
                            min_dist = min(min_dist,subset_dist[(frozenset(S_minusJ),k)]+dist[frozenset([j,k])])
                            subset_dist_new[(frozenset(S),j)] = min_dist 
        subset_dist = subset_dist_new
    return subset_dist_new
```

Comment: After each pass through the main loop (which successively brings more and more cities into play) why don't you simply delete sets that you no longer need? They will be garbage-collected.

Comment: I'm keeping the subsets from previous and current iteration of the loop in the dictionary named subset_dict and subset_dict_new. Were you referring to that? If not, I didn't get you.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand how your algorithm works, but you said that your algorithm "needs only subsets which are of size 1 less than the current subsets" but is storing "the distances corresponding to current and previous sizes". Why store previous sizes if you don't need them for the next iteration? Weed them out. If you *do* need them, then I don't understand what you meant by the first quoted statement.